# Get Checked out items in a document library

Tags: development, 2007, document-library, splist

I have a document library which has 18000 items. When I go to the **All Site Contents** page, I see 18000 items against the document library name.

But when I query the items in C# as

```
foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items)
```

I get a count of just 17000 items

Is it possible that the remaining items are checked-out and thus are not coming in the query(I am an SCA though).

What could be the reason

Comment: How are you querying the count?

Comment: Show me the whole code...

Answer (score 2):

We can get the Checked out files using the below code. No matter what you try, you cannot get the checked out files by querying the document library as these are saved in a separate table in the database.

```
SPDocumentLibrary library = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
IList<SPCheckedOutFile> files = library.CheckedOutFiles;
foreach (SPCheckedOutFile file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.LeafName);
}
```

The count difference was due to the fact that those 1000 items were never checked-in and can be accessed through the above code.